# Adding a LoaderOverlayView above statusBar but without hiding it

Tags: swift

Despite there are similar questions, I haven't been able to find a working solution for my situation.

I am working on an app that does all the UI programatically. In my AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    setupNavigationBarStyle()

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HeadlinesViewController(networkHelper: NetworkHelper.shared))

    return true
}

func setupNavigationBarStyle() {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.statusBarBackground

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.navigationBarBackground
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.navigationBarTint

    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.navigationBarText]

    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false

    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.navigationBarBackground
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.navigationBarTint
}
```

When I am in HeadlinesViewController, I want to show a LoaderOverlayView that covers the whole screen including status bar but it stills shows it as an overlaid view.

The class LoaderOverlayView looks like:

```
public class LoaderOverlay{

    var overlayView = UIView()
    var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    var window:UIWindow{
        return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
    }

    class var shared: LoaderOverlay {
        struct Static {
            static let instance:LoaderOverlay = LoaderOverlay()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    public func showOverlay() {

        //¿¿¿???
        window.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.statusBar

        overlayView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.whiteLarge)
        activityIndicator.center = overlayView.center
        overlayView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()

        window.addSubview(overlayView)

    }

    public func hideOverlayView() {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        overlayView.removeFromSuperview()
        window.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.normal
    }

}
```

By changing the windowLevel, the view is showing but the status bar text is missing. Any suggestion?

**EDIT**

It seems that the problem is when i set the 'statusBarView' background color in 'setupNavigationBarStyle' function which comes from:

```
extension UIApplication {

    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }

}
```

Comment: How do to set up your view constraints ? Show us the code for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally realised that

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.navigationBarBackground
```

was the one giving problems. Once removed, the status bar still gets the same background colour than the navigationBar and it doesn't affect when I show the overlay view.